# How to calculate the Margin of Error in this specific scenario?

Tags: sample, population

Assuming I have a population made of hotel bookings for a specific period and I need to send a survey questionnaire to each guest (guest=booking) by email. 
To simplify things, let us assume the questionnaire has only 1 question, with possible answers being YES or NO.

Let us assume these are the figures relating to the Survey:

Total number of bookings: 13,000

Number of bookings (with email captured): 7,000

Number of questionnaires sent: 7,000

Number of questionnaires received: 3,000

How do I calculate the `Margin of Error` in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that 7000 bookings is the random sample from population of 13000 bookings and 3000 is the random sample from 7000. (If these assumptions are not true, then no statistical methods exist for your problem). Let $x$ be the number of "YES" among 3000 received questionnaires. Then

Standard error = $\sqrt{(1-\frac{3000}{13000})\frac x{3000}(1-\frac x{3000})/3000} $

Margin of error is 1.96 times standard error.